# Converting a generic struct to the same generic struct with different type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, struct

Assuming I have a basic class hierarchy like this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass { }
public class X : BaseClass { }
public class Y: BaseClass { }
```

And I have a generic struct as this:

```
public struct MyStruct<T>
  where T: BaseClass, new()
{
}
```

I can then create an instance as follows:

```
var x = new MyStruct<X>();
```

Now i want to provide an operation (a constructor, or a conversion operator) on `MyStruct`, which allows me to convert `MyStruct<X>` to `MyStruct<Y>`:

```
MyStruct<Y> my = new MyStruct<X>();
```

When i write a constructor as follows:

```
public struct MyStruct<T>
    where T: BaseClass, new()
{
    public MyStruct(MyStruct<T2> value) 
        where T2: BaseClass, new()
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

The compiler does not understand what i'm trying to do (it seems it cannot distinguish between `MyStruct<T>` and `MyStruct<T2>`).

**How do i convert `MyStruct<X>` to `MyStruct<Y>` from within `MyStruct<T>`?**

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this in the constructor, but you should be able to write a conversion method in the struct, something like:

```
public struct MyStruct<T>
    where T: BaseClass, new()
{
    // Convert this instance of MyStruct<T> to a new MyStruct<TOut>
    public MyStruct<TOut> ToMyStruct<TOut>()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Which would allow you to write:

`struct2 = struct1.ToMyStruct<TOut>()`

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a conversion operator? So that client code doesn't have to explicitly call a specific method?

Answer (score 2):

C# has no concept of generic conversion operators; any conversion operator, whether implicit or explicit, must either import or export a type which is fully defined by the generic parameters of the defining type.  This means that `Foo<T>` can define a conversion operators to or from `Bar<T>` (and vice versa), and `Foo<T,U>` can define conversions to or from `Bar<U>`, but not vice versa.  It also means that a `Foo<T>` can define conversions to or from `Bar, but not vice versa.  Unfortunately, there is no way to have a conversion operator which can import or export a type with generic type parameters beyond those of the defining type, even if the parameters would be constrained in such a way that the cast would succeed.

What all this means is that one must often use methods rather than operators to perform conversions (or, for that matter, to perform mixed-type operations).  Generic type resolution for methods is pretty smart (at least if one is willing to include a default-null dummy parameter) but for operators it's pretty limited.

Incidentally, if the only purpose for which a struct uses a generic type parameter is to define public fields of that type, it should in theory be possible for such a struct to support covariance without regard for whether the structs are "mutable", since an assignment of a `KeyValuePair<FordFocus,SiameseCat>` to a `KeyValuePair<Vehicle,Animal>` would represent the assignment of a `FordFocus` to a `Vehicle` and a `SiameseCat` to an `Animal`, both of which are type-safe.  This fails, however, because all boxed structures are always mutable, and mutable aspects of a type cannot safely support covariance.

Answer (score 2):

I made it work using the following approach:

```
public static implicit operator MyStruct<T>(MyStruct<X> value)
{
    return new MyStruct<T>(value);
}

public static implicit operator MyStruct<T>(MyStruct<Y> value)
{
    return new MyStruct<T>(value);
}

....
```

This is limited to known types (X, Y, ...), but lets me write the following code:

```
MyStruct<X> x = new MyStruct<X>(...);
MyStruct<Y> y = x;
```